# Error : Opening Emulator handleCpuAcceleration after Upgrading Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

After upgrading **Android Studio** to **Arctic Fox**, I am getting errors while opening Emulator.

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7583922, built on July 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows Server 2019 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true, ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.ankit.mahadik.json.dart.class, com.herbert.george.flutter-snippets, com.intellij.marketplace, Dart, org.moe.community, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, io.flutter, pl.pszklarska.pubversionchecker
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below lines to `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` (create this file if it doesn't exist)

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

for Windows `.android` folder is located in `C:\Users\{username}\.android`

Comment: Upvoted for that `off` but what if we want the support of this new feature which makes the emulator faster. Maybe there are other features too that god knows. For that support you have to add `dll` file using these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68590710/1318946).

Comment: Thanks , `vulkan = off` means your emulator is not working with App which is using `Vulkan API`, Vulkan API is used for 3d Graphics.

Comment: That's great. It will be easy to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Download [vulkan-1.dll](https://www.dll-files.com/vulkan-1.dll.html) from the Internet and move it to **C:\Windows**

I downloaded from the above link and renamed it to **vulkan-1.dll**.

And moved to **C:\Windows** folder.

If you have noticed on [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-vulkan), check this description for usage of this dll.

Now you can start your AVD. Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

yes same issue occur for sdk version 30 and not found any solution unitll now.

i have solved this issue by finish emulator process in task manager and then create another emulator with x86 images.

Comment: This is not a solution, not even a workaround.