# Android Emulator does not start after Arctic Fox upgrade, libvulkan.so: failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-arctic-fox

Trying to start an emulator in Android Studio gives me the following error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30_-_GooglePlay has terminated.

I get the following errors logged in Android Studio logs:

```
2021-08-11 13:38:19,827 [ 290921]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: /home/werner/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapshot-load -avd Pixel_4_API_30_-_GooglePlay 
2021-08-11 13:38:19,885 [ 290979]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf 
2021-08-11 13:38:19,927 [ 291021]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: cannot add library /home/werner/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed 
2021-08-11 13:38:19,933 [ 291027]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: added library /home/werner/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so 
2021-08-11 13:38:20,091 [ 291185]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) 
2021-08-11 13:38:20,091 [ 291185]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
```

The error boils down to:

> cannot add library /home/werner/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed

This is under Ubuntu 20.04 with Android Studio 2020.03.1 and the emulator plugin version 30.7.5.0.

What I've seen/tried:

- I have already tried creating a new emulator, but the same issue occurs.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288845/435093) is similar but the solution is for macOS
- [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67380028/435093) suggesting uninstallation and reinstallation of the Emulator plugin also didn't work for me
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68600054/435093) suggests another config, which also leads to a segmentation fault (`handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf [1]    1694643 segmentation fault (core dumped)`, but no Vulkan-related error messages

When I run the emulator with `-gpu guest`, everything works fine.

This means that when I manually change the file `~/.android/avd/Pixel_4_API_30_-_GooglePlay.avd/config.ini` to set `hw.gpu.mode` from `auto` to `guest`, it runs fine. I consider this a workaround and not a real solution, as HW rendering will not not work anymore, and with SW rendering, the System UI of the emulator keeps crashing every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was solved by updating the system packages via:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

In my case, it was installing the latest version of `mesa-vulkan-drivers` that probably fixed the issue. I hadn't upgraded my system in a while.

Answer (score 6):

My solution was similar to @slhck but instead I changed Nvidia GPU drivers to use the recommended version.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Answer (score 1):

If `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` fails, you can also select the latest proprietary driver yourselve:

- Open "Additional Drivers" in the Ubuntu Launcher
- Select the latest proprietary driver listed here
- `Apply` (this takes a while) and reboot your system

[image]